# Statistical approach to compare the SNP genotyping data among set of individuals

Tags: snp, phylogenetics, snp-chip

So, I have the genotyping data of about 650,000 SNPs for 96 individuals. I already know the Y DNA haplogroup of these individuals, so to some extent, I have a gross understanding of their ancestry.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? From what I have been reading, maybe a PCA would be a good idea? Suppose individuals 1-10 belong to a particular population (unique ancestary) then their SNP genotypes should be significantly similar to each other than say individuals 11-20 who belong to another population group. So, in theory I should get two clusters in my PCA plot.

I have the genotype of each SNP for each individual. How would I go about creating a PCA plot or any other alternative way of analysis for this kind of questions.

Comment: Way better. Now one of your question is, "how to make a PCA plot". There are the plenty of tutorials out there, have you tried one? Yes? What what was the problem with it?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCA sounds like a good start to see a rough population structure among your 96 individuals, this step is half a sane thing to do, but also it can give you a hint how many distinct populations there are in your dataset. I have not personally run PCA on SNP data, but it seems that there are quite lot of tutorials online. For instance [this one](https://privefl.github.io/bigsnpr/articles/how-to-PCA.html) looks  nice.

Once you know how many categories you can expect in your population, you can use [Structure](https://web.stanford.edu/group/pritchardlab/structure.html) to classify individuals to the categories.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't able to make it clear, but ya that's precisely what I want to do. I want to see if the individuals cluster in any manner whatsoever. Did you mean PCA by any chance in your answer? So exactly how would I go about doing it. I know what PCA does in theory but I am not able to understand how I can create a PCA plot with the data I have in hand.

Comment: @user2887 Oh, yes. I meant PCA, fixed that already. Note that you can also edit your question, to make it clearer or to add more details.

Comment: Hey, I edited the answer (added a link to a blogpost where they show how to do PCA on SNP data). Seems that quite lot of them out there if you google "pca genotype data".